# How to translate into Ukrainian words: look, see, watch

Tags: переклад, from-english

Are there any differences in the Ukrainian language?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These words could be translated as бачити, дивитися, оглядати depending on context. For example:

> What are you looking at? - На що ти дивишся?
>      Have you ever seen that? - Ти раніше це бачив?
>      Are you going to watch this movie? - Ти будеш переглядати це кіно?
>      I don't see anything wrong with that. - Я не вбачаю в цьому нічого поганого.

Also there are several of other forms and synonyms exist for these words. For instance:

> Why you're staring at me? - Ти чого витаращився?

Also these words could mean absolutely different things with the following contexts:

> Look at these skills! - Неймовірно!
>     Are you looking for something? - Ти щось шукаєш?
>     Do you see the difference? - Відчуваєш різницю?
>     This lady looks good. - Ця жіночка файно виглядає.

Comment: "Витаращився" - хіба не "витріщився"?

Answer (score 12):

- ***Look*** is дивитися (for some time), [по]глянути, [по]дивитися (have a look, a short action), виглядати (appear, seem):

  > What are you looking at? — На що ти дивишся?
  >
  > Look, they are kissing! — [По]глянь/[по]дивись, вони цілуються!
  >
  > You look tired today. — Сьогодні ти виглядаєш втомленим.
- ***See*** is бачити, розуміти (I see):

  > Can you see those guys? They're my friends. — Бачиш тих хлопців? Вони мої друзі.
  >
  > — There's nothing between me and her. — Між нами нема нічого.
  >
  > — I see. — Розумію/Зрозуміло.
- ***Watch*** is дивитися (attentively, for a long time), спостерігати (watch closely), споглядати (contemplate)

  > I never watch TV. — Я ніколи не дивлюся телебачення/телевізор.
  >
  > My friend is fond of watching birds. — Мій друг любить спостерігати за птахами.
  >
  > Jack is a Buddhist monk, he spends all his days in meditation watching the Nothing. — Джек – буддистський монах, він проводить всі дні в медитації, споглядаючи Ніщо.