# Слухаєш, але не чуєш, чи чуєш, але не слухаєш?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів

Якось мене попросили перекласти українською крилатий вислів:

**Дивитися, але не бачити, слухати/чути, та не чути/слухати.**

Стосовно першої частини сумнівів не виникло, а от стосовно другої - виникла дискусія.

Згідно [словника](http://sum.in.ua/):

> ЧУТИ́ - Сприймати за допомогою органів слуху які-небудь звуки.
>
> СЛУХАТИ - Спрямовувати слух на створювані ким-, чим-небудь звуки;
>   намагатися сприймати що-небудь слухом.

Отже, логічно було б припустити, що людина сприймає звуки на слух, однак, не намагається їх сприйняти, зрозуміти. Тому моїм варіантом було:

*Дивитися, але не бачити, чути, але не слухати*

Однак, у багатьох джерелах - навпаки. [Тут](http://www.novapedahohika.com/noloms-309-4.html):

> Отже, дивитись ще не означає бачити, а слухати — не означає чути.
>   Потрібна спеціальна організація діяльності учнів у цьому напрямі.

[І тут](https://uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0:Ivan_Ohienko_Bible.djvu/1207):

> 13 Я тому́ говорю́ до них при́тчами, що вони, ди́влячися, не бачать, і
>   слухаючи, не чують, і не розуміють.

Отже: **чи є "правильна" версія і чому?**

UPD: [аналогічне обговорення англійською](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358990/you-hear-but-you-dont-listen-or-you-listen-but-you-dont-hear)

Comment: Related: http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/104/

Comment: тут можна побачити як в [англійській версії](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2013:13) намагаються передати через аспекти дієслів. Зверніть особливу увагу на _"they do not hear or understand"_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 1. Про вислів, що треба перекласти.

У даному конкретному випадку треба просто зрозуміти, яке з дієслов другого протиставлення відповідне якому з дієслов першого:

[*Чути*](http://sum.in.ua/s/chuty) відповідає [*бачити*](http://sum.in.ua/s/bachyty), а [*слухати*](http://sum.in.ua/s/slukhaty) відповідає [*дивитися*](http://sum.in.ua/s/dyvytysja), бо ([як вже зазначено в коментарях](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/641/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%94%D1%88-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%83%D1%94%D1%88-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%83%D1%94%D1%88-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%94%D1%88/642#comment1645_641)) перші два дієслова - то пасивні дії, а другі - активні.

Тому в цьому конкретному випадку кажемо:

*Дивитися, але не бачити, слухати, та не чути.*

Тобто, людина виконує дію (дивиться, слухає), але це не дає результату (не бачить те, що хоче / повинна / мала би побачити дивлячись. Не чує того, що хоче / повинна / мала би почути слухаючи).

### 2. Відповідь на головне запитання: *Слухаєш, але не чуєш, чи чуєш, але не слухаєш?*

Можливі обидва варіанти в різних ситуаціях:

- Див. пункт 1.
- *Чути, але не слухати* значить, що звуки доходять до органів слуху (вух), але людина не сприймає інформацію, що надходить до мозку. Тобто, хтось пасивно отримує інформацію, але не докладає зусиль (активна дія *слухати*), щоби її сприйняти чи зрозуміти.

Answer (score 10):

Скажімо так, обидві версії з логічної точки зору можливі:

1. «Слухаєте, але не чуєте» — акцентує, що інформація таки не доходить до «мозку» (не сприймається свідомістю); «чуєте» тут в значенні «повністю сприймаєте свідомістю» (а не лише «сприймаєте органами чуттів»); а «слухаєте» не в значенні «зосереджено намагаєтеся зрозуміти», а радше «поверхнево, неуважно слухаєте».
2. «Чуєте, але не слухаєте» — тут, як Ви кажете, «чуєте» позначає, що інформація доходить до органів чуття (але не обов'язково «мозку»), а «слухаєте» — «намагаєтеся сприйняти, зрозуміти».

Але. Я би не вживав другий варіант за Вашим способом. Чому?

- Бо тоді би було обернути і першу частину:

  > Бачите, але не дивитеся; чуєте, але не слухаєте.

  Бо «дивитися» і «слухати» в семантичному плані схожі: вони обидва можуть позначати *направленість уваги на щось* (зорової чи слухової) — але *не обов'язково повної/достататньої (і не обов'язково разом зі свідомістю).*

  І «бачити» й «чути» в семантичному плані схожі: вони обидва можуть *сприйняття чогось* — але як *сприйняття поверхневе* (органами чуттів), так і *сприйняття глибоке* (самою свідомістю).

  На цьому базується те, що теоретично обидві конструкції мають сенс:

  > Дивитеся, але не бачите; слухаєте, але не чуєте.
  >   Бачите, але не дивитеся; чуєте, але не слухаєте.
- Бо другий варіант фрази можна вдаліше сформулювати іншими словами:

  > <s>Бачите, але не дивитеся; чуєте, але не слухаєте.</s>
  >   Бачите, але не вдивляєтеся; чуєте, але не вслухаєтеся.

Тобто мій вибір:

1. > Дивитеся, але не бачите; слухаєте, але не чуєте.
2. > Бачите, але не вдивляєтеся; чуєте, але не вслухаєтеся.